# What is the connection of this synchronous motor?

Tags: motor

[image: motor]

so yeah I took this picture of the terminal box of the synchronous motor we're cleaning. I can't distinguish what is wye or delta when it's shown like this. what are the indications that a connection is wye/delta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the three power lines for a delta connection must be connected to one end of two of three phase coils. That is what is shown.

For a wye connection, each of the three power lines must be connected to one end of one of the three phase coil. The other end of each phase coil must be connected together to form a neutral. There is no external connection to the neutral. That connection would be made if the three jumper links were to be removed and replaced to connect together either the red, orange and yellow leads or the blue green and black leads. The three leads without jumper links would be the power connections. Only two links would be required, but the third would be stored on top of one of the other two.

The wye connection would look something like this:

[image]

Comment: what do you mean when you said "the third would be stored on top of one of the other two"? are you saying that there should be a physical link between the yellow and red leads?

Comment: In the delta connection, there are three jumper links. The wye connection requires only two. The unused jumper is installed as a double layer in parallel with one of the required links so it will be available if the motor needs to be connected in delta sometime.

Answer (score 0):

There are   3 Nodes.  Where is Neutral? (Not there)
This is how Δ wiring looks .

Comment: It could be Y without a neutral connection. Sure, if there is an unbalanced supply you might get some issues of course but an unbalanced supply causes issues anyway. Not disagreeing.